# Even Now.... or Even Until Now... Placement Ambiguity

Tags: word-usage

> Sentence A : The boy's body has been devoured by disease

I want to place ***even now***, and i have a few alternatives :

> 1. ***Even until now*** the boy's body has been devoured by disease
> 2. The boy's body has been devoured by disease ***even now***.

Question : Now the question where should i place the "even now" so that it would sound more natural as a native speaker would do. Please correct me.

Comment: The question is one of strangest exercises I have seen. First, I'm not sure if there is a real usage of "even until now" besides scriptures and poems. It might sound better if it were "up until now" instead. Secondly, I'm not very sure but "even now" makes me think that I would need the "present tense", not the "present perfect".

Comment: A native speaker is very unlikely to use either (1) or (2).

Comment: Can you change the rest of the sentence?  I wouldn't put *even now* or *even until now* into the sentence the way it is.

Comment: I might use them that way, but not without commas, and probably **not** with **both** *until* **and** *even*. I can't say for certain without additional context, but I might say: *Even now, the boy's body has/had been devoured by disease.* -or- *The boy's body has been devoured by disease, until/even now* (as in after treatment). -or- *Until now, the boy's body had been devoured by disease.*

Comment: @DamkerngT., *even now* can be used for *still*, *even still*, *up till this point in time*, etc. I'd consider it informal at best, however. And Present perfect functions similar to simple present here syntactically. Present perfect can have relevance to the present. *At this point [even now], I haven't found a better way to express this thought, despite my efforts to the contrary.* If this is speech, I've got no objection to *even now*. I probably wouldn't write it that way though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Even now* has two meanings

- with a verb in the 'simple' construction it means ‘still, in spite of [some circumstance]’

  > Even now, after all he had learned, he believed in her innocence.
- with a verb in the progressive construction it may have that meaning, or it may mean ‘at this very moment’

  > He is pleading even now, even as we speak, with the Prime Minister to pardon her.

But *even now* is not used with a perfect construction in either of these senses.

I suspect what you mean is one of these:

> Even now the boy's body is being devoured by disease.
> Right up **until** now the boy's body has been devoured by disease.

In either case, the adverbial phrase is a sentential modifier and may be moved after the first auxiliary (*is/has*), after *devoured* or to the end of the sentence. It's permissible to move it after the second auxiliary (*being/been*), but I find that pretty clunky.